# Width and height of <picture> element when lazy loading

Tags: html, image

https://pastebin.com/2AY6s2tm

**html**

```
<picture>
   <!-- _1_1_2, _16x9 -->
   <source srcset="/media/img/raster/4fe4c2e2-b8f3-4c88-a06d-2f44e76f53ef/img_width_70_height_39_dpr_1x_ver_4.webp 1x" type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 359px)">
...
   <source srcset="/media/img/raster/4fe4c2e2-b8f3-4c88-a06d-2f44e76f53ef/img_width_339_height_190_dpr_1x_ver_4.jpg 1x" type="image/jpeg" media="(min-width: 1920px)">
   <img loading="lazy" width="70" height="39" src="/media/img/raster/4fe4c2e2-b8f3-4c88-a06d-2f44e76f53ef/img_width_239_height_134_dpr_1x_ver_4.jpg" alt="Trololo">
</picture>
```

**css**

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Well, **lazy loading**.

Images should include width and height.
Documentation: https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#images-should-include-dimension-attributes

If we don't include width and height, layout shifts can occur.

So, if we include width and height, then a clever browser calculates its proportions. And allocates the necessary space for the element.

Please, have a look at the image. I stipulated width = 70 and height = 39.
This seems reasonable. This image's aspect ratio is 16 : 9.

height = 70 * 9/16 = 39.375 ~ 39.

If I'm not mistaken, exact pixels are not important here: screens will always be different in mobile world.

**Problem**

As we can clearly see, width fits the width of the parent element. But the height is still 39. It has not been recalculated.

And of course, this distorted the whole aspect ratio of the image.

Could you help me here.

[image]

Comment: I would imagine if you set in CSS `width:100%;` you also need to explicitly set the `height:auto;`?

Comment: does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture give any help?

Comment: working. thank you very much. if you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine if you set in CSS `width:100%;` you also need to explicitly set the `height:auto;`.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You may also find some structural advice here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I needed the parent Div from the beginning in the right size). I solved it getting the image size from the file (php):

```
$data = getimagesize("path/to/file");
```

calculating the aspect ratio:

```
$aspectratio = $data[0]/$data[1];
```

an set it as css style to the parent div:

```
<div class="portfolio-wrap" style="aspect-ratio: '.round($aspectratio,1).';">
   <img/>
</div>
```